# I have a code and need to print out in put in different order but it keeps printing it out in brackets

Tags: python, string, dictionary

So here is the code and I need the output to be printed in a different way and with out brackets. How do I do that?

```
    phonebook = {}
    n=1
    line = str(input('Name and clour: '))
    while line:
      name, colour = line.split()
      phonebook[n] = name, colour
      line = str(input('Name and clour: '))
      n=n+1
    print(phonebook[3])
    print(phonebook[1])
    print(phonebook[2])
```

Comment: it stores them as python tuples..

Comment: try printing like this: ```print(phonebook[3][0] + " " + phonebook[3][1])```

Comment: try: `print(*phonebook[3]);
print(*phonebook[1]);
print(*phonebook[2]);' (i.e. * before each print for unpacking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while condition comes out to be `True` always so, the program keeps on asking for 
`name` and `colour`. Since, the highest number for the `key` is `3` so i changed the condition to `n<4`. So, this program works fine only if the number is in `phonebook[key]` is `key=3`.

```
phonebook = {}
n=1
#line = str(input('Name and clour: '))
#while line:
while n<4:
    line = str(input('Name and clour: '))
    name, colour = line.split()
    phonebook[n] = name, colour
    n=n+1
print(phonebook[3])
print(phonebook[1])
print(phonebook[2])
```

Also,

```
keys = [1,2,3]
for k in keys:
    name, colours = phonebook[k]
    print(name, colour)
```

this prints name and colour without brackets

Comment: Thank you really helpped all though not quite what I was looking for

Comment: yeah, may be, i did the modifications based on your question. please specify the way you want the output to be.

Comment: Sorry I think I did not.